# Django 3 multi-base not working when migrate

Tags: django, database, django-orm, django-migrations

I use Django 3 with 3 apps: security, historian, bench. 
Each app has its own database.
in the **settings.py**:

```
DATABASE_ROUTERS = [
    'security.router.securityRouter',
    'bench.router.benchRouter',
    'historian.router.historianRouter', 
    ]

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': 'DB_DJANGO',
        'HOST': 'LOCALHOST\\SQLEXPRESS',
        'PORT': '1433',
        'USER': 'user',
        'PASSWORD': '******',
        'OPTIONS':{
            'driver': 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server',
        }
    },
    'BdBench': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': 'BD_Bench',
        'HOST': 'LOCALHOST\\SQLEXPRESS',
        'PORT': '1433',
        'USER': 'sa',
        'PASSWORD': '5eCUr1tE',
        'OPTIONS':{
            'driver': 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server',
        }
    },
    'BdBenchMeas': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': 'BD_Bench',
        'HOST': 'LOCALHOST\\SQLEXPRESS',
        'PORT': '1433',
        'USER': 'user',
        'PASSWORD': '******',
        'OPTIONS':{
            'driver': 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server',
        }
    },
    'BdSecurity': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': 'BD_Security',
        'HOST': 'LOCALHOST\\SQLEXPRESS',
        'PORT': '1433',
        'USER': 'user',
        'PASSWORD': '******',
        'OPTIONS':{
            'driver': 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server',
        }
    },
    'BdHistorian': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': 'BD_Historian',
        'HOST': 'LOCALHOST\\SQLEXPRESS',
        'PORT': '1433',
        'USER': 'user',
        'PASSWORD': '******',
        'OPTIONS':{
            'driver': 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server',
        }
    },
}
```

I use for each app: a router.py file:
to **security / router.py**:

```
class securityRouter(object):
    APPS = ['security', 'auth', 'sessions', 'contenttypes']
    BD = 'BdSecurity'

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label in self.APPS:
            return self.BD
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label in self.APPS:
            return self.BD
        return None

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        if obj1._meta.app_label in self.APPS and obj2._meta.app_label in self.APPS:
            return True 
        return None     

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        if app_label in self.APPS:
            return db == self.BD
        return None
```

to **historian / router.py**:

```
class historianRouter(object):
    APPS = ['historian']
    BD = 'BdHistorian'

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label in self.APPS:
            return self.BD
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label in self.APPS:
            return self.BD
        return None

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        if obj1._meta.app_label in self.APPS and obj2._meta.app_label in self.APPS:
            return True 
        return None     

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        if app_label in self.APPS:
            return db == self.BD
        return None
```

to **bench / router.py**:

```
class benchRouter(object):
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label == 'bench':
            if model._meta.model_name == 'measurement':
                return 'BdBenchMeas'
            else:
                return 'BdBench'
        else:
            return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label == 'bench':
            if model._meta.model_name == 'measurement':
                return 'BdBenchMeas'
            else:
                return 'BdBench'
        else:
            return None

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        if obj1._meta.app_label == 'bench' and obj2._meta.app_label == 'bench':
            return True  
        return None       

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        if app_label == 'bench':
            return db == 'BdBench'
        return None
```

When I migrate for each of the apps:
    `python manage.py migrate security`
    `python manage.py migrate historian`
    `python manage.py migrate bench`

I get:
in BD_Security database has no tables
in BD_historian database has no tables
in The BD_Bench database has the bench and historian tables.
in DB_DJANGO database has only one table *django_migrations*

I use this tuto [django-multidb](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.2/topics/db/multi-db/)

why I don't migrate correctly my apps / models ?

Somebody to help me ?!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you migrate using different databases should always add a `--database` switch if it isn't the default database. It says so in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.2/topics/db/multi-db/#synchronizing-your-databases), first paragraph.

Like this:

```
python manage.py migrate security --database BdSecurity
```